# How to Display only 3 related product on product view page, Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4

I  am displaying related products in **content** block of layout in product view page. My code in **catalog.xml** is:

```
<reference name="content">
     <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" after="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Now, all the related products are displayed in my product view page, but I want to display only 3 products, What should I do? Please, anybody can help ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to edit the template file `catalog/product/list/related.phtml` and limit the loop to only iterate through 3 products.

For example:

```
    ...
    <?php $i = 0; ?>
    <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
        <?php if($i++ == 3) break; ?>
        ...
```

Comment: thnx @zitix, it worked for me. Though its static, but worked for now. :)

Comment: here you will be getting a bigger collection while you want only three. so this will be more resource intensive.In your collection code add this limit of 3.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me.
You have to limit the query, and maybe shuffle it before loading the collection. Open the file \app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List\Related.php and look for the method:

> Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Related->_prepareData()

Add this line before the load() call.

```
$this->_itemCollection->getSelect()->limit(3)->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
```

It is still not pretty, **!!you should not write in the core code!!**, but it's a good start.

Comment: This is the perfect answer. Just to add, one should rewrite the class

Comment: this is wrong method because you overwrite core files. You must write model to extend this class if you need change code logic.

Comment: @Nerjuz Translation: "It's the wrong method because it's not the one I want". Go away!

Answer (score 1):

You have a collection of products prepared in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Related` and it is iterated in the template file `catalog/product/list/related.phtml`.
If you have any rule that should add to limit your collection, you can override the _prepareData() method and modify the collection.
If not, the easiest solution is to exit from the loop in the phtml after three iterations.